# Extract text of OneDrive documents using Graph Api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I have been using Ms Graph API, to download the files of OneDrive successfully.

I was looking for a way to read only the text content (for indexing purpose in my application) using Graph API, for different types of files(pdf,xls,zip,Images etc.) instead of going by the conventional approach of downloading the complete file and then extracting the text using some "Text extracting api" and then index the file, which would be a time consuming task. I am aware GraphAPI has its own search features, but it lacks ability to do complicated search like regular expression search  (please correct me if I am wrong). I am sure OneDrive does its own indexing for each file which helps a user to do the basic search.

So, is there any way I can get the text content of the documents using the Graph API?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe getting a 'preview' of text-based documents is currently available through the API. You will need to make a `GET` request to fetch the content. If you don't want the full document, you can [request a partial range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_get_content#partial-range-downloads') of bytes that you believe would be enough for the document. In addition, to make it easier to handle different file types, we currently support [converting common file formats to PDF](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_get_content_format) (to possibly standardize your file parsing logic).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Can I use the "Converting to PDF" approach for Email Attachments as well? I have similar requirement for reading O365 Mailbox attachments.

Comment: Is there a way I can do a regular expression search on the drive items. I know there is a search capability in the Graph API,but nowhere it mentions whether it can do a regular expression search or not.

Comment: Sorry - I don't believe either of these are possible today (RegEx $search, or attachment conversion to PDF).

Comment: Thanks for that. An off topic question, Does Graph API support Yammer?  I was not able to find any info about it on the web.

Comment: In beta, we have [APIs for fetching info about Yammer activity](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/yammer_activity_reports)